# material-ui Select Box not showing selection

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a material-ui select box that is populated with a state variable. No matter what I have tried, I cannot get the value to actually show when I select an option. Can anyone tell me why? It keeps just giving me a blank bar. I even took an example from another code sandbox and copied it almost exactly. One thing I did notice is that my event.target.value is always undefined, and I am not sure why. So I just use value, instead, in my handleChange function. Any help is greatly appreciated! This has been driving me crazy.

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jnyq16279v

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import Select from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

export default class KKSelect extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectOptions: [
                {
                    value: "Image",
                    id: "1"
                },
                {
                    value: "Integer",
                    id: "2"
                },
                {
                    value: "Decimal",
                    id: "3"
                },
                {
                    value: "Boolean",
                    id: "4"
                },
                {
                    value: "Text",
                    id: "5"
                }
            ],
            selectedValue: ""
        };
    }

    renderSelectOptions = () => {
        return this.state.selectOptions.map((dt, i) => {
            return (
                <MenuItem key={i} value={dt.id}>
                    {dt.value}
                </MenuItem>
            );
        });
    }

    handleChange = (event, value) => {
        this.setState({ selectedValue: value });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider>

                <Select
                    value={this.state.selectedValue}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                >
                    {this.renderSelectOptions()}
                </Select>

            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you are using material-ui version 0.20.1 - docs for that version is here: https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field, but it's recommended to use v1 (https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/).

For version 0.20.1, there are few problems with your code:

First: renderSelectOptions: {dt.value} should be assigned to MenuItem primaryText

```
renderSelectOptions = () => {
        return this.state.selectOptions.map((dt, i) => {
            return (
                <MenuItem key={i} value={dt.id}>
                    {dt.value}
                </MenuItem>
            );
        });
    }
```

like this:

```
renderSelectOptions = () => {
    return this.state.selectOptions.map((dt, i) => (
      <MenuItem key={dt.id} value={dt.id} primaryText={dt.value} />
    ));
  };
```

And second - handle change has event, index and value arguments, so your value is acctually index - not value.

```
handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ selectedValue: value });
};
```

Should be:

```
  handleChange = (event, index, value) => {
    this.setState({ selectedValue: value });
  };
```

Check out working version for material-ui version 0.20.1 here: https://codesandbox.io/s/9q3v1746jy

P.S. If you are using material-ui version 1.2.1, I made working example for that version too, you can check it out here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jjvrnokkv3

Comment: Thank you so much! Your examples and explanations were very clear, so I really appreciate it! Helps me learn a lot better =)

Answer (score 0):

it could be solve by using custom styling in listbox props . plz refer my code .

```
 <Autocomplete
            key={`${filterKey}-township`}
            onChange={onAutocompleteChange}
            disableClearable
            multiple
            fullWidth
            limitTags={1}
            value={value}
            disableCloseOnSelect={true}
            size="small"
            id="township"
            options={townships}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.Township}
            ListboxProps={{
               style: {
                  position: "absolute",
                  top: 10,
                  bottom: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  height:300,
                  width: "100%",
                  overflowY: "auto",
                  backgroundColor: "white",
               },
            }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
               <TextField
                  {...params}
                  variant="standard"
                  label="Township"
                  onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
               />
            )}
            renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
               <React.Fragment>
                  <Checkbox size="small" icon={icon} checkedIcon={checkedIcon} checked={selected} />
                  <Typography variant="body2">{option.Township}</Typography>
               </React.Fragment>
            )}
         />
```